# Django Form validation error for default value

Tags: django, forms, validation, model, default

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer


class Customer(models.Model):
    balance = models.FloatField(default = 0.0)

form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # is FALSE
```

When I submit a form without a `balance` field, I get a validation error saying that the balance field is required. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You can help add a `clean_FIELDNAME` method to the form that returns `0.0` as default.
This method is called during the cleaning process of the form.

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    balance = models.FloatField(required=False)

    def clean_balance(self):
        if not 'balance' in self.cleaned_data or self.cleaned_data['balance'] is None:
            return self._meta.model._meta.get_field('balance').default
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['balance']
```

Another way to handle this is to use the forms clean method to kick the balance field out of the cleaned_data and let the model set the default.

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer

    def clean(self):
        if 'balance' in self.cleaned_data and self.cleaned_data['balance'] is None:
            del self.cleaned_data['balance']
        return self.cleaned_data


class Customer(models.Model):

    balance = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=False, default=0.0)
```

Comment: Only problem with this is need to define default value in clean method as well and don't fallback to default value set in model.

Comment: Changed the clean_ method to use the default value of the model.

Answer (score 1):

`required=False` is enough to write for not checking `balance` field in `forms.py` .

Also put `blank=True` and `default` value to `balance model` field

No need to use `clean` method here. because `clean` is used whenever you are looking for custom validation.

There is two method for custom validation in django form -:

1) you can use `clean` method.

2) you can use `forms.regexfield`.